# How to restore a deja-dup backup using a ubuntu booted from usb live?

Tags: 18.04, backup, deja-dup

I had my hd broken and now I'm using a live ubuntu booted from a usb.

I need to restore my backup into a external hard-drive.

I was able to start deja-dup and select my backup hd, but it gives a `permission denied`error. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission denied calls for insufficient permission, try launching `deja-dup` using `sudo` it should work then.